# New facebook api problems

Tags: node.js, facebook

In my app, i have the choise to do search in facebook using the next sentences:

```
var uri="https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=#KEY#&q=#QUERY#&type=post";

uri=uri.replace("#QUERY#", busqueda);
uri=uri.replace("#KEY#", apiKey);
```

But now in the new api, 
    var uri="https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=#KEY#&q=#QUERY#&type=post"; is deprecated. I will like to know is it possible to do something similar to this.

I have tried to use app id and app secret but it dosent works, i want to avoid to chance code. Exist any option to do the similar without using the next function?

```
FB.init({
  appId      : '{your-app-id}',
  status     : true,
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.3' // or v2.0, v2.1, v2.0
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you want to use the FB JS SDK with Node.js, but coming to your main question:

No, it's no longer possible to search for public posts:

> Public Post search is no longer available. (`/search?type=post&q=foobar`)

And no, there's no workaround for this.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

Comment: I have read that, my app is make with Node.js i supose i need to adapt then my code.

Comment: Not only that, but also what you want to achieve is not possible anymore.

Comment: For example is i want to find all events that contain the word Madrid, https://www.facebook.com/search/results/?q=madrid&type=all, is possible to do this from an app using the token generated?

Comment: Look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#search Why are you talking about events now, your question was about posts

Comment: Now i understand all, before path you could search into post, now only in event, people, places.... ty.

Comment: Yes is a good help, var uri="https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=#KEY#&q=#QUERY#&type=EVENT";, is possible then to do something like this?